# Wordpress auto insert post_id in the post_title for a cpt

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

I'm looking for the snippet code to allow me to automatically insert the post_id for each new post in wordpress (CPT "property")

the reason: I have several posts with the same style of title like
"hello world" for example

if I have 10 posts with hello world .. how to differentiate them in the post_title?

I don't know if this kind of code snippet exists
but it will save me a lot of time to copy / paste

"hello world - id 2140"

"hello world - id 2141"

"hello world - id 2142"

new post >
(your post name here) - id 2143

if you have an idea please share

[image]

EDIT :

I found this [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251179/possible-to-create-a-new-post-and-have-the-title-and-slug-automatically-use-the) which talks about the same thing.

it seems like it's...not really possible

because post_id is generated when I click on publish

how could it display an id to a new post when it's not yet generated?
I think I will still have long copy/paste days to come...

Comment: Always explain what you tried before. As a reminder SO isn't a free "please code for me" service.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple sql:

```
UPDATE wp_posts set post_name = concat(post_name, ' - id ', id) where UPPER(post_name) = 'HELLO WORLD';
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the ID after the title of *each*  post you can edit the templates of your theme, for example the `index.php` file, the `single.php` file, `page.php` etc. and add `echo get_the_ID();` right after `the_title()` in the PHP code of those templates.

BTW: I'd create a *child theme* in this case because any theme update will overwrite those template files. (see https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ for more on that subject)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for some function hooked to `save_post`.

As of WP 3.7, an alternative to the `save_post` action has been introduced, which is called for specific post types: [`save_post_{post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/). In your case we can use the `save_post_property` hook to intercept the post title and apply changes to it (where property refers to the dynamic part `_{post_type}`).
Hooking to this action prevents your callback to be unnecessarily triggered. It fires once a post has been saved (like `save_post`).

We need to discard any updates, autosaves or [revisions](https://wordpress.org/support/article/revisions/) actions. The WordPress autosave system fire every 60 seconds.

The `$update` parameter from `save_post_{post_type}` is supposed to determined whether this is an existing post being updated. It applies more specifically to a post autosave revision. The `$update` parameter will always be true when firing through `wp_publish_post`. But that isn't true for its usage in `wp_insert_post`.

- @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185991/190376

In our case, the [`wp_publish_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_publish_post/) function publish a post by transitioning the post status.

By additionally crosschecking the post status we can effectively determine whether it is indeed a non-existing post.

A few more things: If you are calling a function such as `wp_update_post` that includes the `save_post` hook, your hooked function will create an infinite loop. To avoid this, unhook your function before calling the function you need, then re-hook it afterward.

- @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/#avoiding-infinite-loops

`save_post_{post_type}` will fire on post `update` (eg: autosave) or `publish` which is why we're running into an infinite loop.

- @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19539/190376

```
<?php

add_action( 'save_post_property', function ( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    if ( ! wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) && ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && ! $update && $post->post_status == 'auto-draft' ) {

        $title = $post->post_title;
        $title .= ' - ID ';
        $title .= $post_id;

        $slug = sanitize_title( $title );

        remove_action( 'save_post_question', array( $this, 'automatically_generate_the_custom_post_type_question_title' ), 10, 3 );
                    
        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_title' => $self,
            'post_name' => $slug,
        ) );
                    
        add_action( 'save_post_question', array( $this, 'automatically_generate_the_custom_post_type_question_title' ), 10, 3 );

    };

}, 10, 3 );
```